# Gulp tasks throw an error on Win 10

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I have windows 10 Pro,
doing an exercise from here https://vk.com/video-160048630_456239048?list=b31c949319120bc599

Have installed gulp, gulp-less, gulp-notify, gulp-plumber.

I have created gulp tasks that turn .less file into the .css.

When I run my gulp tasks it throws an error:

```
$ gulp default

$ gulp 'default'
assert.js:42
  throw new errors.AssertionError({
  ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
    at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (C:\Users\Anatoly\Desktop\project\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:10:3)
    at Gulp.task (C:\Users\Anatoly\Desktop\project\node_modules\undertaker\lib\task.js:13:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Anatoly\Desktop\project\gulpfile.js:8:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

My gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),

    browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
    less        = require('gulp-less'),
    notify      = require('gulp-notify'),
    plumber     = require('gulp-plumber');

gulp.task('server',['less'],function(){

    browserSync.init({

        server: {baseDir: './app/'}
    });

    gulp.watch('app/**/*.html').on('change',browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('app/less/**/*.less',['less']);
});

gulp.task('less',function(){

    return gulp.src('./app/less/main.less')
        .pipe(plumber({
            errorHandler: notify.onError(function(err){
                return {
                    title: 'less',
                    sound: false,
                    message: err.message
                }               
            })      
        }))
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('default',['server']);
```

Comment: I try to unistall gulp locally and install specific version of gulp, less than 4.0.0

Answer (score 1):

The problem disappeared after I reinstalled gulp with a less version:

`npm uninstall gulp`  -- removes gulp
`npm i gulp --save-dev`  --installs local version 3.9.1

Run gulp task:

```
gulp server
```

It works.